# Field Question Proofs

Tags: field-theory, proof-writing

True or False:

In every field $F$, if $x,y$ belong to $F$ and $w,w'$ belong to $F$
such that $x * w = 1$ and $y * w' = 1$, then $(x * y) * (w * w') = 1$.

I think the answer would be false mainly because if we look at the chart for fields we get that anything multiplied by $0$ is $0$.

Comment: Where is something multiplied by 0? Hint: use associativity and commutativity of multiplication.

Comment: can you show me with an example please.

Answer (score 0):

This is true. I will use commutativity, associativity and the two given equations throughout.

$\begin{eqnarray*}
x \cdot y \cdot w \cdot w' &=& x \cdot w \cdot y \cdot w' \\
&=& 1 \cdot 1 \\
&=& 1
\end{eqnarray*}$

Comment: dam I was close so just mixed up the right side thnx